# jquery autocomplete IE6 ascii issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete, internet-explorer-6

I am using jquery autocomplete version 1.1. It works perfectly in all browsers except IE6. In IE6 it returns ascii codes starting with a question mark in the autocomplete dropdown. The code works perfectly on my local mahcine when im debugging in IE6. However when it is hosted it behaves errorneously.

Any suggestions please !

Comment: What you mean 'errorneously'? Some source and results please.

Comment: Kushal, the jquery autocomplete 1.1 plugin is deprecated; it has now been rolled into the official jQuery UI package.  Changing this is recommended anyway, and might also resolve any other problems you have.  A migration guide is available (http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/autocomplete-migration-guide) and the docs for the jQuery UI version are also available http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/.

Comment: I have tried to change it but in IE 6 it gives me the following return ?[o]. I checked the issue and opened the path to the autocomplete ashx and passed the query string explicitly. e.g. domainname/autocompletetagdata.ashx?q=t; where t is my search text. and in another instance of the browser tried t as search text, then it gives me a valid return I am using the following link as a reference ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-autocomplete.html; it gives the same error in IE6

Answer (score 0):

Are you explicitly setting your character encoding with a meta tag in the page headers? Does the encoding on the page match the encoding of your data source for auto-complete (assuming it has one)?

I'd try setting everything you can possibly think of to an explicit charset and see if it helps. You can also add the `accept-charset` attribute to the form element itself (would advise using UTF-8 unless you have good reasons not to).

Comment: I have tried to change it but in IE 6 it gives me the following return ?[o]. I checked the issue and opened the path to the autocomplete ashx and passed the query string explicitly. e.g. domainname/autocompletetagdata.ashx?q=t; where t is my search text. and in another instance of the browser tried t as search text, then it gives me a valid return.

Comment: I am using the following link as a reference http://www.ajaxdaddy.com/demo-jquery-autocomplete.html; it gives the same error in IE6